# Error with Visual Studio 2008 setup

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msdn

Every time I run the Visual Studio setup I encounter the following error message *"A problem has been encountered while loading the setup components. Canceling setup."*. I also tried running the setup via the control panel, which results in a ever-so-meaningful "path not found" (but the setup did execute further).

I did try removing several patches as statet on MSDN, reinstalling SP1 but no effect.

There is also a "Hot Fix for Visual Studio 2008" which handles exactly that case - but it didn't work either.

I'm don't want to remove VS completely because I'm afraid that the setup will fail then as well - and I need VS for work.

I'll make a full backup of my pc and try removing VS later. Maybe than it will work. If not - I will have to reinstall my pc :(

Unfortunately the web isn't helping much here.

Any help? Ideas? Anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the solution was to deinstall the Visual Studio 2008 SP1 first, then add the missing components and then reinstall the SP1 again.

No problems during setup anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pain, but I'd try a full uninstall and reinstall.

If VS isn't working then you have nothing to lose by uninstalling it and reinstalling it from scratch. Even if it is working, a fresh install (of anything) is almost always preferable to a patched and hacked install.

If you can run VS, then go to Tools->Import and export settings, and export all your settings. This same menu item will allow you to import your settings after the reinstall, allowing you to quickly get back to a fully working setup.